# Integer comparison in Bash using if-else

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have a variable called `choice`. Now, I try to use if to compare the entered value:

```
read $choice

if [ "$choice" ==  2  ];then
       #do something
elif [ "$choice" == 1 ];then
       #do something else
else
     echo "Invalid choice!!"
fi
```

The output goes directly to invalid choice if I enter either 1 or 2. I tried to put quotes around 1 and 2 inside the if statement. Still didn't work. Using `-eq` gives me an error "Unary operator expected".What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your `read` line is incorrect. Change it to:

```
read choice
```

i.e. use the name of the variable you want to set, not its value.

`-eq` is the correct test to compare integers. See `man test` for the descriptions (or `man bash`).

An alternative would be using arithmetic evaluation instead (but you still need the correct `read` statement):

```
read choice

if (( $choice == 2 )) ; then
    echo 2
elif (( $choice == 1 )) ; then
    echo 1
else
    echo "Invalid choice!!"
fi
```

Comment: Now I feel utterly dumb. :( Thanks for your help (and the quick reply), Mat!!

Comment: you mean "its" value; if "it is" doesn't sound right then "it's" isn't

Comment: Hmmm, coping and pasting this with a BusyBox sheel seems to fail. 

When, for example, I enter 2 for choice, I get the errors... 
-ash: 2: not found
-ash: 2: not found

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: ash isn't bash. Try devnull's case variant, it's more portable.

Answer (score 6):

For your example, `case` seems to be what you probably want:

```
read choice

case "$choice" in
"1")
    echo choice 1;
    ;;
"2")
    echo choice 2;
    ;;
*)
    echo "invalid choice"
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 4):

An unpractical answer, just to point out that since `read` takes a variable name, the name can be specified by another variable.

```
choice=choice   # A variable whose value is the string "choice"
read $choice    # $choice expands to "choice", so read sets the value of that variable
if [[ $choice -eq 1 ]]; then   # or (( choice == 1 ))
```