# Bash only printf if cron = 0

Tags: bash, cron

I'm pretty new to this bash scripting, but looking forward to learn a lot more about it. But I'm stuck here where I'm trying to only make the script to do the `printf` if the value of `cron=0` else nothing, but continue the script. I'll get an error on the line "`then printf`" and the script fails if i change the cron value to anything but `0`

```
cron=0

if ! [ -w ${dest_dir} ]
    then
    if (${cron} == 0)
     then printf "%s\n" "Eureka! ${dest_dir} is write protected!!"
    fi
    else
    exit 1
fi
```

Someone who could tell me what's wrong and give me a push in the right direction?

**Update 1**

Do to my question of clever bash guys I got this lovely quick answer [ "$value" = x ] && exec >/dev/null 2>&1 will redirect both stdout and stderr to /dev/null if your value is x (per a string comparison, as opposed to a numeric comparison).

Unfortunately I do not quite understand how to use that I practice to hoping for a little real example vs my script

So how should I implement it into this

```
#If value cron=0 do printf, if value cron=1 do not printf
cron=0
if ! [ -w "${dest_dir}" ]
    then
    if [ "${cron}" -eq 0 ]
     then 
     printf "%s\n" "Eureka! ${dest_dir} is write protected!!"
    fi
    else
    exit 1
fi

for i in "${FILES[@]}"
do
    file=${dest_dir}"$i"

if [ -f "${file}" ]
then
    if ! [[ -w "${file}" ]] ; then
    printf "%s\n" "'${file}' is write protected!!"
        exit 1
    fi
fi

done
```

Comment: FYI -- `[ -w "$dest_dir" ]` -- the quotes are necessary, otherwise you'll get a response of truth/success even if the `dest_dir` variable is empty.

Comment: BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ will catch this mistake for you automatically (both the missing quotes, *and* the `( )` used instead of `[ ]`).

Comment: As an aside, `[` isn't language syntax for the shell -- it's actually a *command*. Just as there's a `/usr/bin/test`, there's also a `/usr/bin/[` (or `/bin/[` and `/bin/test`, depending on your OS), so in terms of `[` needing spaces around it, it's just like every other command (like how you can't run `ls-l` but need to run `ls -l`). That there's also a builtin in the shell providing a higher-performance version than the external `[` is somewhat moot in terms of how it's parsed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Have tested it on shellcheck but it didn't tell me why :(

Comment: I paste your code straight from the question, and I get this for line 5: `^-- SC2205: (..) is a subshell. Did you mean [ .. ], a test expression?` -- that's the exact problem, and following the link to https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2205 describes it in extra detail.

Comment: Exactly :) that tells me nothing as rookie to this :/

Comment: It's telling you should be using `[ ]`, and gives you a link to a web page that explains how and why in detail. Did you actually follow the link (that's there in the shellcheck output) and try reading it?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it does now, as I have read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18161265/7581259 :) I was literally blank before...

Comment: BTW, the `(( ))` arithmetic-context syntax given in that answer is bash- or ksh-only. If you want something that's guaranteed to work with all versions of `#!/bin/sh`, instead of only bash, then `[ "$value" -eq 0 ]` is actually the Right Thing. (Now, by contrast, `$(( ))` is guaranteed to work in all POSIX shells, but `(( ))` without the leading `$` is an extension).

Comment: Also, you have an `else` keyword in the wrong place: `if condition; then code; else code; fi`

Comment: hi @glennjackman that one is already fixed, but thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your if to:

```
 if [ "${cron}" -eq 0 ]
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18161265/7581259

Comment: thx @Theo and Charles for both your replies, that helped me a lot. But thoose guys writing the bach scripting, did they think about a method to simply silence all echo/printf if a value = x for an entire script, rather than having to put this if into all occurrences?

Comment: @Joakim, of course. `[ "$value" = x ] && exec >/dev/null 2>&1` will redirect both stdout and stderr to `/dev/null` for the rest of your script if your value is x (per a string comparison, as opposed to a numeric comparison).